# Is this business halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, business, awrah

AssalamuAlaykum. I'm trying to go into the cosmetology niche with web design. Meaning I create websites for businesses that specialize with cosmetology. Or even cosmetology schools. I know in these websites they show women with their hair and sometimes even awrah because that's what they teach you to do. How to cut hair, do nails, etc. Is it permissible to create websites for these people? The money I get means nothing if Allah doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

AssalamuAlaykum. In response to your question about venturing into the cosmetology niche with web design, it's important to understand that any profession, including web design, is not inherently prohibited in Islam. However, it's crucial to conduct your work in accordance with Islamic principles. It is well known that displaying images, especially of women, can be problematic. Therefore, when developing websites for these businesses or schools, it would be wise to establish some rules that align with Islamic laws and share these with your clients. You could also select themes that are compliant with Islamic Laws. Indeed, the process may be challenging, but remember, for Muslims, faith (Iman) holds precedence over material gains. I hope this response provides clarity, but please feel free to ask additional questions if you have any.

Comment: Thank you brother. I don't want to transgress Allah's rules. So I decided to go and do a similar niche which is Dental. I believe it is more in fit with Islamic principle. Thank you.